# Issue with getting a single item in list

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm having an issue getting a single item in a list. The list compromises of menu ids and I would like to get the specific id as opposed to the whole list.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
// list of menus ids
const select_menu_ids = ["menu1", "menu2" ];

// filter through the list seems to return the whole list instead of item in list
const ids = select_menu_ids.filter((menu_id) => menu_id); 

// the statement that checks the id in the list
if (customId === `${ids}`) {...
```

Comment: What you do here is just filter to get just items which are not 0 or '' or undefined or null.
What item do you want it to return to you ? The first one ? The last one ? A random one ? A specific one with a given value ?

Comment: @Lucasbk38 I want to return specific values that are in the list as opposed to all values which show as `[ 'menu1', 'menu2' ]` in the console.  So I want the values in the list to be read individually.

Comment: If you want to run some code for every item, you should use some kind of for loop, if you just want to verify if some item is in the array, use Array.prototype.includes (as shown in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what to want is to check is a `customId` is inside the `select_menu_ids`, your `if` check should be something like this :

```js
// list of menus ids
const select_menu_ids = [ "menu1", "menu2" ];

if (select_menu_ids.includes(customId)) { ... }
```